# Google API, stats given by API differs from the GA website

Tags: google-analytics

I have an issue with Google Analytics : the stats given by the API are differents from those which come from the Google Analytics website.

Here is what the API is giving me

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '08' (length=2)
      1 => string '121' (length=3)   // 121 pagesviews
```

And here are all parameters I give to GA in order to get this result

- Start date : **2014-08-01**
- End date : **2014-08-31**
- metrics : **ga:pageviews**
- dimension : **ga:month**
- filters : **ga:hostname==my-host-name.fr**

Finally, here is what the GA dashboard is telling me when I put the same parameters Audience Overview:

[image]

I think i’va made a mistake, because there is a huge difference between this two results but all parameters are identical. Can somebody help me please ?

Thank you.